# How can I use RusTLS to encrypt a byte slice using a known public key and PKCS1 padding?

Tags: ssl, rust

In order to create GitHub releases from Travis CI, you need to use [public keys they provide](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/) to encrypt secrets which can be checked into a project.

I've successfully managed to do this using [the openssl crate (v0.10.11)](https://docs.rs/openssl/0.10.11/openssl/):

```
extern crate base64;
extern crate openssl;

use openssl::rsa::{Padding, Rsa};
use std::{error, fs};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn error::Error>> {
  let data = b"some data";

  let pub_key = fs::read_to_string("./key.pem")?; // Read the public key.
  let rsa = Rsa::public_key_from_pem(pub_key.as_bytes())?;

  let mut res = vec![0; rsa.size() as usize];
  rsa.public_encrypt(data, &mut res, Padding::PKCS1)?;

  let encrypted = base64::encode(&res);
  println!("Encrypted Data: \n{}", encrypted);
  Ok(())
}
```

[*link to repro*](https://github.com/yoshuawuyts/repro-stackoverflow-keys)

However, using OpenSSL comes with a few tradeoffs. Most notably: getting cross platform builds to work [requires some work](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl/issues/977).

I've been looking at [rustls](https://docs.rs/rustls/0.13.1/rustls/) as an alternative, and was wondering what the equivalent of the code above is.